# Missing docbookxi.xsd

Tags: xsd, docbook

Seems that the `/docbook-5.0/catalog.xml` (XML catalog) found in the DocBook 5.0 zip ...

- http://www.docbook.org/xml/5.0/docbook-5.0.zip

references a `xsd/docbookxi.xsd` schema file that seems to be missing from that archive.

Is this just a placeholder for some functionality that is yet to exist, or is this a legitimate error/bug/oversight in that catalog file?

Doing some google searching for `docbookxi.xsd` just turns up hundreds of references to this DocBook xml catalog reference, but no reference to the actual docbookxi.xsd file / definition.

Due to limitations in the environment i'm working with, I cannot use the alternative RELAX NG versions of this schema.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, that's a legitimate bug. I don't actually recall if the toolchain that built the (awful) XSD versions was ever able to produce the XInclude version.

I can try to create an XInclude version of the "by hand" XSD files. However, that will be a version 1.1 XML Schema. Is that good enough, or do you need 1.0?

[Addendum]

After some investigation, it appears to me that the UPA rule in XSD makes creating an XInclude version enormously difficult. Simply allowing XInclude at either the division level (part or reference) and the component level (preface, chapter, et. al.) violates the UPA rule because a book can start with either a division or a component.

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps http://docbook.org/xsd/5.0b2/docbook-xsd10.xsd or http://docbook.org/xsd/5.0b2/docbook.xsd is what you are looking for?  Since [the XSD schema documents for Docbook are now maintained by hand](http://norman.walsh.name/2011/12/19/docbookXSD), it may well be that there are versions of the normative Relax NG schema for which no corresponding XSD schema document is provided.

Comment: Sadly those are missing the xi:include bit in order to validate a docbook xml file before it has been resolved into the uber file.